# How do I handle special characters in a Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I'm using a Perl program to extract text from a file. I have an array of strings which I use as delimiters for the text, e.g:

```
$pat = $arr[1] . '(.*?)' . $arr[2];

if ( $src =~ /$pat/ ) {
   print $1;
}
```

However, two of the strings in the array are `$450` and `(Buy now)`. The problem with these is that the symbols in the strings represent end-of-string and capture group in Perl regular expressions, so the text doesn't parse as I intend.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 16):

Try Perl's [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) function. Alternatively, use `\Q` and `\E` in your regex to turn off interpolation of values in the regex. See [perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#More-on-characters%2c-strings%2c-and-character-classes) for more on `\Q` and `\E` - they may not be what you're looking for.

Comment: Specifically, \Q won't protect against backslash-escaped characters. quotemeta is by far the more general solution.

Comment: @BenBlank: What are you talking about?  `\Q` *compiles into* `quotemeta`. They are the same function. Similarly, `\L` compiles into `lc`, `\U` into `uc`, etc. `\Q` “protects against” backslash-escaped characters perfectly well, because **it is `\Q` after all!**

Answer (score 11):

quotemeta escapes meta-characters so they are interpreted as literals.  As a shortcut, you can use \Q...\E in double-quotish context to surround stuff that should be quoted:

```
$pat = quotemeta($arr[1]).'(.*?)'.quotemeta($arr[2]);
if($src=~$pat) { print $1 }
```

or

```
$pat = "\Q$arr[1]\E(.*?)\Q$arr[2]";  # \E not necessary at the end
if($src=~$pat) { print $1 }
```

or just

```
if ( $src =~ /\Q$arr[1]\E(.*?)\Q$arr[2]/ ) { print $1 }
```

Note that this isn't limited to interpolated variables; literal characters are affected too:

```
perl -wle'print "\Q.+?"'
\.\+\?
```

though obviously it happens after variable interpolation, so "\Q$foo" doesn't become '\$foo'.

Answer (score 6):

Use [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html):

```
$pat = quotemeta($arr[1]) . '(.*?)' . quotemeta($arr[2]);
if ($src =~ $pat) 
    print $1;
```