# How do I handle every ASCII character (including regex special characters) in a Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl, ascii, split, csv

I have the following code in Perl:

```
if (index ($retval, $_[2]) != -1) {
    @fs = split ($_[2], $_[1]);
```

`$_[2]` is the delimiter variable and `$_[1]` is the string that the delimiter may exist in. (`$_[0]` is used elsewhere) You may have guessed that this code is in a subroutine by those variable names.

Anyway, onto my question, when my delimiter is something innocuous like `'a'` or `':'` the code works like it should. However, when it is something that would get parsed by Perl regex, like a `'\'` character, then it does not work like it is supposed to. This makes sense because in the split function Perl would see something like:

```
split (/\/, $_[1]);
```

which makes no sense to it at all because it would want this:

```
split (/\//, $_[1]);
```

So with all of that in mind my question, that I cannot answer, is this: "How do I make it so that any delimiter that I put into `$_[2]`, or all the ASCII characters, gets treated as the character it is supposed to be and not interpreted as something else?"

Thanks in advance,

Robert

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I handle special characters in a Perl regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576435/how-do-i-handle-special-characters-in-a-perl-regex)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) to escape `$_[2]` properly so it will work in the regex without getting mangled. This should do it:

```
my $quoted = quotemeta $_[2];
@fs = split( $quoted, $_[1] );
```

Alternatively, you can use \Q in your regex to escape it. See "Escape Sequences" in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org//perlre.html).

Comment: Thankyou, It worked right of the bat. Problem solved. One tick for you.

Answer (score 6):

```
split /\Q$_[2]/, $_[1]
```

Comment: You are right this is one of the ways I can do it but my tick has to goto the other guy because his worked perfectly off the bat. This generated an error.

Comment: No "@fs = " and no semicolon? That's all I can think of (besides PEBKAC). Otherwise its just as good as the other answer.

Comment: Sorry, It was my fault, It works just fine. However, friedo did give alot more information and description so I do not feel too bad about selecting his as the accepted answer; I am sorry, but I will leave my choice as is.

runrig: There is no reason to say the PEBKAC; I'm obviously new.

Comment: I'm not complaining about choice of "correct" answer, merely seeing if my post needed updating ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, I'm suspecting that the `$_[1]` and `$_[2]` variables refer to the automatically passed in `@_` array of a sub.

It's helpful - would have saved you quite some explaining here and made your code more understandable by itself - and common practice to use something like the following at the beginning of the sub:

```
sub mysub {
  my ($param1, $string, $delim) = @_;
  # ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I should think about this but I'm pretty new to Perl and I'm finding that I'm treating it a little too much like C. So thanks for the heads up.