# How can I escape a literal string I want to interpolate into a regular expression?

Tags: regex, perl

Is there a built-in way to escape a string that will be used within/as a regular expression? E.g.

```
www.abc.com
```

The escaped version would be:

```
www\.abc\.com
```

I was going to use:

```
$string =~ s/[.*+?|()\[\]{}\\]/\\$&/g; # Escapes special regex chars
```

But I just wanted to make sure that there's not a cleaner built-in operation that I'm missing?

Comment: I also answered this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893067/how-can-i-match-in-a-regular-expression/1894320#1894320

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I handle special characters in a Perl regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576435/how-do-i-handle-special-characters-in-a-perl-regex)

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[How do I handle special characters in a Perl regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576435/how-do-i-handle-special-characters-in-a-perl-regex)*.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) or [`\Q...\E`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Escape-sequences).

Consider the following test program that matches against `$str` as-is, with `quotemeta`, and with `\Q...\E`:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $str = "www.abc.com";

my @test = (
  "www.abc.com",
  "www/abc!com",
);

sub ismatch($) { $_[0] ? "MATCH" : "NO MATCH" }

my @match = (
  [ as_is => sub { ismatch /$str/ } ],
  [ qmeta => sub { my $qm = quotemeta $str; ismatch /$qm/ } ],
  [ qe    => sub { ismatch /\Q$str\E/ } ],
);

for (@test) {
  print "\$_ = '$_':\n";

  foreach my $method (@match) {
    my($name,$match) = @$method;

    print "  - $name: ", $match->(), "\n";
  }
}
```

Notice in the output that using the string as-is could produce spurious matches:

```
$ ./try
$_ = 'www.abc.com':
  - as_is: MATCH
  - qmeta: MATCH
  - qe: MATCH
$_ = 'www/abc!com':
  - as_is: MATCH
  - qmeta: NO MATCH
  - qe: NO MATCH
```

For programs that accept untrustworthy inputs, be extremely careful about using such potentially nasty bits as regular expressions: doing so could create unexpected runtime errors, denial-of-service vulnerabilities, and security holes.

Answer (score 13):

The best way to do this is to use `\Q` to begin a quoted string and `\E` to end it.

```
my $foo = 'www.abc.com';
$bar =~ /blah\Q$foo\Eblah/;
```

You can also use `quotemeta` on the variable first. E.g.

```
my $quoted_foo = quotemeta($foo);
```

The `\Q` trick is documented in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) under "Escape Sequences."