# How can I get my Perl regex not to use special characters from an interpolated variable?

Tags: regex, perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I escape meta-characters when I interpolate a variable in Perl's match operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001176/how-can-i-escape-meta-characters-when-i-interpolate-a-variable-in-perls-match-op)

I am using the following regex to search for a string `$word` in the bigger string `$referenceLine` as follows :

```
$wordRefMatchCount =()= $referenceLine =~ /(?=\b$word\b)/g
```

The problem happens when my `$word` substring contains some `(`, etc. Because it takes it as a part of the regex rather than the string to match and gives the following error :

```
Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in 
m/( <-- HERE ?=\b( darsheel safary\b)/ 
at ./bleu.pl line 119, <REFERENCE> line 1.
```

Can somone please tell me a solution to this? I think If I could somehow get perl to understand that we want to look for the whole `$word` as it is without evaluating it, it might work out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```
$wordRefMatchCount =()= $referenceLine =~ /(?=\b\Q$word\E\b)/g
```

to tell the regex engine to treat every character in `$word` as a literal character.

`\Q` marks the start, `\E` marks the end of a literal string in Perl regex.

Alternatively, you could do

```
$quote_word = quotemeta($word);
```

and then use

```
$wordRefMatchCount =()= $referenceLine =~ /(?=\b$quote_word\b)/g
```

One more thing (taken up here from the comments where it's harder to find:

Your regex fails in your example case because of the word boundary anchor `\b`. This anchor matches between a word character and a non-word character. It only makes sense if placed around actual words, i. e. `\bbar\b` to ensure that only `bar` is matched, not `foobar` or `barbaric`. If you put it around non-words (as in `\b( darsheel safary\b`) then it will cause the match to fail (unless there is a letter, digit or underscore right before the `(`).

Comment: But from [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) "Because the result of "\Q STRING \E"  has all metacharacters quoted, there is no way to insert a literal $  or @  inside a \Q\E  pair. If protected by \ , $  will be quoted to became "\\\$" ; if not, it is interpreted as the start of an interpolated scalar." Now I'm confused as they seem in disagreement :(

Comment: @pst: Are you sure about that? http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html suggests otherwise. I don't know Perl any more than I can read the docs, so I can't try it here.

Comment: I used \Q....\E...so now I got rid of the error but the matching does not seem to work now. It does not match the substring in the bigger string.

Comment: If your substring really is `( darsheel safary` then it can't match because the `\b` before it will not match. This has nothing to do with the interpolation.

Comment: Hi Tim, I tried that too. Doesnt match still. This is the output I am printing just  FYI,                                                             Ref Line After :  ( darsheel safary ) ! eight - year - old school ! . animals : ishaan ' s " failures " 
We could not find the word in REFERENCE : ( darsheel safary )

Comment: To explain: `\b` matches between an alphanumeric character and a non-alphanumeric character, so it won't match before a `(` unless there is a letter, digit or underscore right before it.

Comment: ohhhh....I didnt consider that case...before I was matching only words after scrubbing off special chars...Now our prof changed the assignment to have special chars in it...Thanks so much!

Comment: `$variable` interpolation still works; it is just that special characters aren't treated as special by the regex engine. And indeed if `$variable` could possibly contain special characters, `/\Q$variable\E/` is the best way to go (and is good defensive programming even if you think the variable is clean).