# How can I escaped regular expression metacharacters from an interpolated variable in Perl?

Tags: perl, string, replace

I need to create an "obscuring" function which replaces a clear-text password in line, before writing it to a log.

It looks like this:

```
function pass_obscure {
      my $logline = shift;
      my $pass = "wer32pass$";   # This password is an example. The real one is received as a parameter, or already stored as a global value.

      $logline =~ s/$pass/*********/g;

      return $logline;
}
```

But this, of course, doesn't work. The '$' sign in the password string is interpolated as an endline character, so there's no match, and so replacement doesn't work.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: ok, sorry, already resolved.

The solution, of course, is to use:

       my $pattern = quotemeta $pass;
       $logline =~ s/$pattern/********/g;

Thanks anyway

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I handle special characters in a Perl regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576435/how-do-i-handle-special-characters-in-a-perl-regex)

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[How do I handle special characters in a Perl regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576435/how-do-i-handle-special-characters-in-a-perl-regex)*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Why not just keep the password out of the log line in the first place?)

Use `quotemeta`:

```
$pass = "password\$";
$logline = "password is: password\$";

print "$pass\n";
print "$logline\n";
$pass_quoted = quotemeta($pass);

$logline =~ s/$pass_quoted/********/g;

print "$logline\n";
```

Outputs:

```
password$
password is: password$
password is: ********
```

Comment: Hi Mikey

Thanks for the answer, I didn't see it in time.

Regarding your first question - it is not up to me. I run the command, which includes password, and I log it. So before I log the command, I want to replace the password with stars. :-)

Thanks

Comment: Yeah, figured there was a sensible reason :)

Answer (score 2):

In interpolated strings,

`\Q` → `quotemeta`
`\L` → `lc`
`\l` → `lcfirst`
`\U` → `uc`
`\u` → `ucfirst`
`\E` → end of the case/quote modifier

Thus this is also a solution.

```
$logline =~ s/\Q$pass/********/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution, of course, is to use:

```
  my $pattern = quotemeta $pass;
  $logline =~ s/$pattern/********/g;
```