# Why does my Perl regex complain about "Unmatched ) in regex"?

Tags: regex, perl

```
if($title =~ s/(\s|^|,|\/|;|\|)$replace(\s|$|,|\/|;|\|)//ig)
```

$title can be a set of titles ranging from President, MD, COO, CEO,...

$replace can be (shareholder), (Owner) or the like.

I keep getting this error. I have checked for improperly balanced '(', ')', no dice :(

```
Unmatched ) in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(\s|^|,|/|;|\|)Owner) <-- HERE (\s|$|,|/|;|\|)/
```

If you could tell me what the regex does, that would be awesome. Does it strip those symbols?  Thanks guys!

Comment: If you are having meta characters in $replace you should use \Q or quotemeta for consider that characters as a normal characters

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576435/how-do-i-handle-special-characters-in-a-perl-regex

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If the variable $replace can contain regex meta characters you should wrap it in `\Q...\E`

```
\Q$replace\E
```

To quote Jeffrey Friedl's Mastering Regular Expressions

> **Literal Text Span**  The sequence **\Q** "Quotes" *regex* metacharacters (i.e., puts a backslash in front of them) until the end of the string, or until a **\E** sequence.

Comment: Short and sweet! It did the job. Could you please elaborate \Q and \E?

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned, it'll strip those punctuation symbols, followed by the contents of $replace, then more punctuation symbols, and that it's failing because $replace itself contains a mismatched parenthesis.

However, a few other general regex things: first, instead of ORing everything together (and this is just to simplify logic and typing) I'd keep them together in a character class. matching `[\s^,\/;\|]` is potentially less error-prone and finger friendly.

Second, don't use grouping parenthesis a set of `()` unless you really mean it. This places the captured string in capture buffers, and incurs overhead in the regex engine. Per `perldoc perlre`:

WARNING: Once Perl sees that you need one of $& , $` , or $' anywhere in the program, it has to provide them for every pattern match. This may substantially slow your program. Perl uses the same mechanism to produce $1, $2, etc, so you also pay a price for each pattern that contains capturing parentheses. [Source](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

You can easily get around this by just changing it by adding `?:` to the parenthesis:

`(?:[\s^,\/;\|])`

Edit: not that you *need* non-capturing grouping in that instance, but it's already in the original regex.

Comment: +1, but I think the `^` and `$` were meant as anchors, so they can't go inside the character classes.  That means the groups *are* necessary: `(?:^|[\s,;|\/])`, `(?:[\s,;|\/]|$)`

Comment: Learnt something new. \Q$replace\E fixed the issue but thanks a lot Marc.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that your variable `$replace` contains the string `Owner)`, not `(Owner)`.

---

```
$title = "Foo Owner Bar";
$replace = "Owner)";
if($title =~ s/(\s|^|,|\/|;|\|)$replace(\s|$|,|\/|;|\|)//ig) {
    print $title;
}
```

Output:

```
Unmatched ) in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(\s|^|,|/|;|\|)Owner)<-- HERE (\s
|$|,|/|;|\|)/ at test.pl line 3.
```

---

```
$title = "Foo Owner Bar";
$replace = "(Owner)";
if($title =~ s/(\s|^|,|\/|;|\|)$replace(\s|$|,|\/|;|\|)//ig) {
    print $title;
}
```

Output:

```
FooBar
```