# Making Strings Safe for Regular Expressions in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string which I want to use in a regular expression it a way like `m/$mystring_03/` however `$mystring` contains +s and slashes that cause problems. Is there a simple way in Perl to modify `$mystring` to ensure all regular expression wildcards or other special characters are properly escaped? (like all `+` turned into `\+`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I handle special characters in a Perl regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576435/how-do-i-handle-special-characters-in-a-perl-regex)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, use the [`\Q` and `\E` escapes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Escape-sequences):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = "a+";

print
    $text =~ /^$text$/     ? "matched" : "didn't match", "\n",
    $text =~ /^\Q$text\E$/ ? "matched" : "didn't match", "\n";
```

Answer (score 11):

The [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) function does what you are asking for.

Comment: `quotemeta` is the function interface to the `\Q` and `\E` escapes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to escape all special characters for regular expressions in the string you can just as well use rindex like

```
index($_, "$mystring_03")
```

this returns the index of the string in the string you want to test or -1 when no match is found.

Comment: The entire regex might not be not be in the string.

Comment: @Chas. Owens If the entire regex (after quoting) is not in the string, it is not going to match, is it? I am not following... When would a fully quoted regex give different results from a substring check?

Comment: Why mention `rindex` and not mention `index`?

Comment: @mobrule no reason, I edited it becquse there is no reason to start from the end, although AFAICS it would not matter in the problem at hand

Comment: I am talking about something like this: `/(?:full)?name: \Q$name\E/`