# How can I use a variable for a regex pattern without interpreting meta characters?

Tags: regex, perl

```
$text_to_search = "example text with [foo] and more";
$search_string = "[foo]";

if ($text_to_search =~ m/$search_string/)
    print "wee";
```

Please observe the above code. For some reason I would like to find the text "[foo]" in the $text_to_search variable and print "wee" if I find it. To do this I would have to ensure that the [ and ] is substituted with [ and ] to make Perl treat it as characters instead of operators.

How can I do this without having to first replace `[` and `]` with `\[` and `\]` using a `s///` expression?

Comment: I would say get into the habit of using the qr// construct for regular expressions and escaping special regex chars if literal is needed. Quotemeta will quote ALL special regex chars. If you just want to find a literal string in another, use index() instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[How do I handle special characters in a Perl regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576435/how-do-i-handle-special-characters-in-a-perl-regex)*.

Answer (score 80):

Use `\Q` to autoescape any potentially problematic characters in your variable.

```
if($text_to_search =~ m/\Q$search_string/) print "wee";
```

**Update:** To clarify how this works...

The `\Q` will turn on "autoescaping" of special characters in the regex. That means that any characters which would otherwise have a special meaning inside the match operator (for example, `*`, `^` or `[` and `]`) will have a `\` inserted before them so their special meaning is switched off.

The autoescaping is in effect until one of two situations occurs. Either a `\E` is found in the string or the end of the string is reached.

In my example above, there was no need to turn off the autoescaping, so I omitted the `\E`. If you need to use regex metacharacters later in the regex, then you'll need to use `\E`.

Comment: ++. Merely for completeness: You could use the quotemeta function for a similar outcome:
`$text_to_search = quotemeta "example text with [foo] and more"; /$search_string/` But this will change $text_to_search, rather than quotemeta'ing only inside the regex.

Comment: @Hugmeir: That's why you want to `quotemeta` the substring to search for instead. See my answer.

Comment: Don't you need to use `\E` after the variable?

Comment: @CJ7: Not in this case. The `\Q` is automatically turned off at the end of the regex.

Comment: CJ7's \E is correct if `$search_string` is followed by something like `$search_string.*?\s` ... must become `m/\Q$search_string\E.*?\s/`. Ideally edit the answer above to make that clear for ppl coming here for quick answers.

Comment: "Merely for completeness" -- more like for complete failure ... Hugmeir's suggestion is all kinds of wrong.

Answer (score 52):

Use the [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) function:

```
$text_to_search = "example text with [foo] and more";
$search_string = quotemeta "[foo]";

print "wee" if ($text_to_search =~ /$search_string/);
```

Answer (score 24):

You can use `quotemeta (\Q \E)` if your Perl is version 5.16 or later, but if below you can simply avoid using a regular expression at all.

For example, by using the `index` command:

```
if (index($text_to_search, $search_string) > -1) {
    print "wee";
}
```

Comment: That does the job for testing in an `if` context but what about a search and replace context?