# Why am I getting an error assigning a regex string to a variable?

Tags: regex, perl

Here is an example of the code:

`my $testVar = "^.+|gg$";`

That line is causing an error. It says the dollar sign should be escaped but I want the entire line to match that so I need the `^` and `$` characters.

Bit new to Perl and I much rather assign my regex statements to variables for ease of use and not sure how.

Comment: How are you using it? I usually have my regular expressions in `/ /`.

Comment: Well I'm not using it because it crashes on that line but I'd like to do something like this `if ($row =~ $testVar) { .. }`

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616395/perl-regular-expression-using-variable-as-search-string-with-perl-operator-char

Comment: @squiguy: Still getting the error.

Comment: The Dollar Sign is interpolated inside double quoted strings as a variable. There are numerous ways to quote strings in Perl, even regex strings. In fact its so complicated any beginnings at Perl should use the gruesome details of quoting as a search item in perldoc before even attempting to use Perl.

Comment: @sln: So what do I do?

Comment: Start with `perlintro` in the perldocs.

Comment: Also, you can read the `perlop` page in the docs. Scroll down to `Quote-Like Operators`. Covers most of what you need to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If want to produce the string

```
^.+|gg$
```

then you must use one of the following literals

```
my $pat = '^.+|gg$';
my $pat = "^.+|gg\$";
```

Note that `$` must be escaped in double-quoted string literals because `$` marks the start of a variable to interpolate in double-quoted string literals.

But it's simpler with `qr`, and it compiles the pattern for you.

```
my $re = qr/^.+|gg$/;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you should do it:

`$variable =~ /(find something)/;`

If you want to assign a pattern to a variable, here's how you could do it:

```
my $pattern = qr"patern";
my $content = "content";
my @results = $content =~ m/($pattern)/;
```

You'll need, indeed, to escape every special characters.

Comment: I understand you can do this I want to assign the regex match to a variable so I don't have to put the entire regex string in the if statement.

Comment: @John Smith - Actually, Perl has no concept of a `Matching` variable like other languages do. It uses global variabls at all times when it comes to regex. This is the granddaddy of all modern engines and is integrated into the language so deeply you can actually run code inside the regex.

Comment: Perl have the `binding operator` `=~` instead of the `Matching` variable - what as you said, is an much more deeper koncept.