# Perl match regex variable \Q

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to match a regex in perl. The regex needs to be stored in a variable.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4616417/3674780) I got `\Q` to match regex in a variable.

```
$regex = "\\$[0-9] (\\+|\\*) [0-9]";
$str = "$2 * 2";

if ($str =~ /\Q$regex/) {    # regex is: \$[0-9] (\+|\*) [0-9]
    print "Expression found :)\n";
} else {
    print "Expression not found :(\n";
}
```

This matches fine in [regexpal](http://www.regexpal.com/). It also works fine when I use the regex immediately without first putting it in `$regex` (i.e. without the `\Q`). What is the `\Q` doing to mess up my regex?

Comment: `\Q` => http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html Skip \Q altogether and try `$regex = qr/[0-9] (\\+|\\*) [0-9]/;`

Comment: Thanks @Сухой27, I see that this works. I also need to match a `$` in the text. This does not work.

Comment: \$ instead of \\$.

Comment: @Сухой27: No, `\\$` is correct within a double-quoted string. The problem is that `$str = "$2 * 2"` sets `$str` to `' * 2'` because it interpolates the undefined `$2`. See my answer

Comment: I've told him to use qr//

Comment: Why do you use `\Q`? That's precisely the bit that breaks your regex...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\Q` and `\E` pair can be used to escape all non-word characters within a double-quoted string context. For instance

```
perl -E 'say "abc[\Q[..]\E]def"'
```

#### output

```
abc[\[\.\.\]]def
```

I wonder why you think you need it, as it prevents all regex metacharacters from having their special effect. For instance `\Q[0-9]` will match exactly `[0-9]` instead of any single decimal digit

I would write your code like this. Note that I have changed double quotes to `qr//` when defining the pattern to create a *compiled* regex, and to single quotes when defining the target string to avoid Perl trying to interpolate built-in variable `$2` into the string. You *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl program you write

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $regex = qr/\$[0-9] [+*] [0-9]/;
my $str   = '$2 * 2';

if ( $str =~ $regex ) {
    print "Expression found :)\n";
}
else {
    print "Expression not found :(\n";
}
```

#### output

```
Expression found :)
```