# How can I use a string variable that contains square brackets inside a regex pattern?

Tags: perl

Trying to match a string with brackets.

For example:

```
my $foo = "debug_bus[0]";
my $bar = "debug_bus[0][12:0] = some_value;";

if ($bar =~ $foo)
{
    print "Match\n";
}
else
{
    print "No Match\n";
}
```

I would expect "Match" but I keep getting "No Match" which leads me to believe maybe brackets in '[0]' are causing an issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perl regular expression (using variable as search string with perl operator chars included)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616395/perl-regular-expression-using-variable-as-search-string-with-perl-operator-char)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to properly escape ("quote") [metacharacters](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quoting-metacharacters) in your regex using `\Q...\E` (inside) or [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) (outside)

Therefore, you want:

```
$bar =~ m/\Q$foo\E/;
```

Or just:

```
$bar =~ /\Q$foo/;
```

You can omit the `m` when the delimiters are `//`, and you don't really need `\E` in this case because there's nothing else in your pattern.

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
my $foo = "debug_bus[0]";
```

With

```
my $foo = quotemeta "debug_bus[0]";
```

From [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) documentation :

> quotemeta EXPR
>   *Returns the value of EXPR with all the ASCII non-"word" characters backslashed*.

Without using quotemeta, `[0]` is interpreted as a [bracketed character class](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Bracketed-Character-Classes), containing only `0`, and then is equivalent to just `0`.