# How to refer to the matched pattern in perl search and replace from bash command line?

Tags: regex, bash, perl

I want to do search and replace(foo to foobar) with bash using `perl` command:

```
sudo perl -0777 -i -pe s/'foo'/'foobar'/gs a.txt
```

but I don't always know what is 'foo', so I want a variable kind of thing which stores the matched pattern.

Also can I get a substring of the matched pattern? Like 'foo' is replaced with 'oobar'(foo becomes oo)?

Comment: you can use variables in your regex, i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616395/perl-regular-expression-using-a-variable-as-a-search-string-with-perl-operator/4616417

Comment: could you please further explain "Also can I get a substring of the matched pattern? Like 'foo' is replaced with 'oobar'(foo becomes oo)?" ? not really sure what exactly you want

Comment: Could you provide an example in a bash command? I don't know perl.

Comment: @Chris suppose I can refer to the matched pattern "foo" by, let's say, $var, I want to get a substring of $var (like substr($var,1)) which will be "oo", so finally i can replace every instance of "foo" with "oobar". Here I get "oo" from substring of the matched pattern "foo" and I supply the "bar".

Comment: Try `sudo perl -i -0777 -pe "s/$foo/${foo:1}bar/gs" a.txt` or with `sed`, `sudo sed -i "s/$foo/${foo:1}bar/g" a.txt`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Is $foo a variable or pattern? Infact I have a complex pattern to match: `[^u]"some string".format` and refer to its substring in the replacement field.

Comment: You do not need `[^u]`, use `(?<!u)` instead. `sudo perl -i -pe 's/(?<!u)"some string"\.format/u$&bar/g' file` or whatever replacement you need, `$&` is the whole match.

Comment: Of course it would not, you ruined the whole syntax. Note I suggested `-0777` only because you have `s` modifier, but from what you seem to want to match, you do not need either of them.

Comment: You need to re-write the whole question if you want me to post a coherent answer. I do not quite know what works for you, but probably you got the gist of using a negative lookbehind instead of a negated character class.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I did `sudo perl -i -0777 -pe s/'(?<!u)"[^"]".format'/'u$&'/g a.py` where my a.py had one line `a = "vs"+"aa {}".format("cvs")` but it did not work

Comment: What do you want to do with `a = "vs"+"aa {}".format("cvs")`? What is the expected result? Why?

Comment: The expected result is `a = "vs"+u"aa {}".format("cvs")`. Running the command again should not insert another "u".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I wanted negative lookbehind because I don't want to match those format functions with a 'u' already present.

Comment: You probably can even use `sed`: `sed -i -E 's/(^|[^u])("[^"]*"\.format\()/\1u\2/g' abc.txt`. It might not work though with `ur"..."`, `r'...'` etc. string literals.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Man it finally worked! I am not using sed because I want multiline match. And I was missing * after [^"]

Answer (score 1):

Use the [expression evaluation modifier `e`](http://p3rl.org/op#s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualngcer).

```
perl -0777 -i -pe's/(foo)/substr($1, 1) . "bar"/egs' a.txt
```

Comment: This won't work eventually because it will cut and throw away the first char of the match. OP's is an XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

`$&` refers to the entire matched pattern and instead of taking substring of that I used negative lookbehind `(?<!u)` this means any character other than `u`:

```
sudo perl -i -0777 -pe s/(?<!u)'oo'/'u$&'/gs
```

This will match not only any `foo` but any occurrence of `oo` but never `uoo` and replace it with `uoobar`.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you gave, you don't need to use the matched text.

```
perl -pe's/foo\K/bar/g'
```

In the scenario you described, you don't need to use the matched text.

```
perl -pe's/f\Koo/oobar/g'
```

---

That said, `$&` contains the matched text.

```
perl -pe's/foo/$&bar/g'
```

And `$1` contains the text matched by the earliest capture, `$2` contains the text matched by the second earliest capture, etc.

```
perl -pe's/(f)oo/$1oobar/g'
```

And `/e` can be used to treat the replacement expression as code to execute for each match.

```
perl -pe's/foo/ substr($&,0,1)."oobar" /eg'
```

---

- There's no point in using `/s` since the pattern doesn't contain `.`.
- There's no point in using `-0777` since your pattern can't span lines.
- The quotes you used were useless, and it's less noisy to quote the entire program instead of individual sections of it.

Comment: The actual pattern does contain . and I want to span lines. And I'm just comfortable with these quotes :P

Comment: The quotes are just asking for problems. They reduce readability and maintainability. Worse, they are misleading.