# Find words in string

Tags: perl

I would like to show in result three words "hidden". I don't know how to do this. Right now, when I start the program, I don't have effect. I see only my text. How to repair it ? I want to create simple program. I have my string and I want to show words which I want to find in my result.

```
use strict;
my $text='Try to find the hidden string here! Hidden or hidden';
my $a = m/\bhidden\b/;
if ($text=~ $a) {
   print "I found word: $a";
}
else {
   print "No match, sorry.\n";
}
```

Comment: most answers like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616395/perl-regular-expression-using-a-variable-as-a-search-string-with-perl-operator/4616417 compare to m/$a/ removing the m// from a. Try that way!?

Comment: `my $pattt = qr/\bhidden\b/; if ($text =~ /$patt/) { ... }` See [qr](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) operator for generating regex patterns, but you can often also just make  a normal string with the pattern, like `my $patt = '\bhidden\n';`

Comment: show the output you want

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Perl regular expression (using a variable as a search string with Perl operator characters included)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616395/perl-regular-expression-using-a-variable-as-a-search-string-with-perl-operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see how we could debug this problem.

Your first step should be to add `use warnings` to your code. You should **always** include both `use strict` and `use warnings`. They are like Perl's safety nets and only a foolhardy programmer codes without them.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings; # ADDED THIS

my $text='Try to find the hidden string here! Hidden or hidden';
my $a = m/\bhidden\b/;
if ($text=~ $a) {
   print "I found word: $a";
}
else {
   print "No match, sorry.\n";
}
```

Now we get a warning:

> Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at test_re line 8.

Line 8 is this:

```
if ($text=~ $a) {
```

So let's see what is in `$a` (as an aside - please don't use `$a` as a variable name. Firstly, it's a terrible, generic name; and, secondly, Perl uses it as a special variable in the `sort` function):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say'; # ADDED THIS

my $text='Try to find the hidden string here! Hidden or hidden';
my $a = m/\bhidden\b/;
say "\$a is [$a]"; # ADDED THIS
if ($text=~ $a) {
   print "I found word: $a";
}
else {
   print "No match, sorry.\n";
}
```

Now, as well as our warning, we get this output:

> ```
> $a is []
> ```

I don't think you're expecting `$a` to be empty at that point, are you? We can go further and determine whether it's an empty string or an undefined value.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $text='Try to find the hidden string here! Hidden or hidden';
my $a = m/\bhidden\b/;
say "\$a is [$a]";
say "\$a is ", (defined $a ? 'defined' : 'undefined'); # ADDED THIS
if ($text=~ $a) {
   print "I found word: $a";
}
else {
   print "No match, sorry.\n";
}
```

And we see:

> ```
> $a is defined
> ```

So it's an empty string. What do you expect it to be?

Here's where is it set?

```
my $a = m/\bhidden\b/;
```

I'm not sure what you expected this to do, but it actually means "match `\bhidden\b` and assign the result of the match to `$a`". And what does it match against that regex? Well, `m/.../ matches the contents of`$*` by default. (That, incidentally, explains our original "uninitialized value $*" warning - Perl just got the line number wrong by one.)

So what actually happens on that line is that Perl tries to match `\bhidden\b` against `$_`. This fails (as `$_` is undefined) and the match returns a false value (the empty string) that gets assigned to `$a`.

Then your code goes on to run this:

```
if ($text=~ $a) {
```

And, as `$a` is the empty string, it matches (any string will match against an empty string and Perl tells you it has matched `$a` (which still contains the empty string).

I'm not sure what you were trying to do with this line:

```
my $a = m/\bhidden\b/;
```

Perhaps you were trying "pre-compile" the regex in some way. In which case, you were looking for `qr/.../`, not `m/.../`.

So maybe you wanted this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $text = 'Try to find the hidden string here! Hidden or hidden';
my $a = qr/\bhidden\b/; # CHANGED THIS
say "\$a is [$a]";
say "\$a is ", (defined $a ? 'defined' : 'undefined');
if ($text =~ $a) {
   print "I found word: $a";
}
else {
   print "No match, sorry.\n";
}
```

Which gives this output:

> ```
> $a is [(?^:\bhidden\b)]
> $a is defined
> I found word: (?^:\bhidden\b)
> ```

Or, if you want to show what has been matched, rather than the regex that you are matching, then you need to "capture" that text:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $text = 'Try to find the hidden string here! Hidden or hidden';
my $a = qr/\b(hidden)\b/; # CHANGED THIS
say "\$a is [$a]";
say "\$a is ", (defined $a ? 'defined' : 'undefined');
if (my ($matched) = $text =~ $a) { # CHANGED THIS
   print "I found word: $matched"; # CHANGED THIS
}
else {
   print "No match, sorry.\n";
}
```

Which gives us:

> ```
> $a is [(?^:\b(hidden)\b)]
> $a is defined
> I found word: hidden
> ```

Ah, but you want to see all of the words. So capture the matches in an array and use the `/g` option to match multiple times:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $text = 'Try to find the hidden string here! Hidden or hidden';
my $a = qr/\b(hidden)\b/;
say "\$a is [$a]";
say "\$a is ", (defined $a ? 'defined' : 'undefined');
if (my (@matched) = $text =~ /$a/g) { # CHANGED THIS
   print "I found word: @matched";    # CHANGED THIS
}
else {
   print "No match, sorry.\n";
}
```

We now get this:

> ```
> $a is [(?^:\b(hidden)\b)]
> $a is defined
> I found word: hidden hidden
> ```

That only matches two instances of "hidden" as the match is case-sensitive. So turn off the case sensitivity with `/i`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $text = 'Try to find the hidden string here! Hidden or hidden';
my $a = qr/\b(hidden)\b/i; # CHANGED THIS
say "\$a is [$a]";
say "\$a is ", (defined $a ? 'defined' : 'undefined');
if (my (@matched) = $text =~ /$a/g) {
   print "I found word: @matched";
}
else {
   print "No match, sorry.\n";
}
```

Which gives us:

> ```
> $a is [(?^i:\b(hidden)\b)]
> $a is defined
> I found word: hidden Hidden hidden
> ```

But, honestly, I think pre-compiling the regex here is just over-complicating things. I'd write this code like this (removing the `$a` variable completely):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $text = 'Try to find the hidden string here! Hidden or hidden';

if (my (@matched) = $text =~ /\b(hidden)\b/gi) {
   print "I found word: @matched";
}
else {
   print "No match, sorry.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for this piece of code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $text='Try to find the hidden string here! Hidden or hidden';
my $re = qr/(hidden)/i;          # () capture found ignoring case

my @match = $text =~ /$re/g;     # g specifies to look for all accurances

say for @match;                  # output each element of @match
```

Output

```
hidden
Hidden
hidden
```