# Perl Regular Expression - Special Characters in Dynamic Regex

Tags: regex, perl

Simple question (I hope)

I have a dynamic string which contains symbols:  ?, /, etc
Basically it's URL string in a log line in my apache error file

I am parsing my log file, I want to see if a certain instance of a url exists in the line:

URL line to search for:  "http://www.foo.com?blah"

The question mark throws me off, as with any special characters in regex's.  I'm trying the following:

```
my $test1 = 'my?test';
my $test2 = 'this is a my?test blah test';

if ($test2 =~ /$test1/)    {    print "YES!!! \n";}
else   {     print "NOOOO!!! \n";  }
```

This prints NOOOO

```
my $test1 = 'mytest';
my $test2 = 'this is a mytest blah test';

if ($test2 =~ /$test1/)    {    print "YES!!! \n";}
else   {     print "NOOOO!!! \n";  }
```

This prints YES!!!

I need this solution quick.

Thanks a bunch

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I handle special characters in a Perl regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576435/how-do-i-handle-special-characters-in-a-perl-regex)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you *really* need regex? The problem is just a simple substring search...

```
if (index($test2, $test1) >= 0)    {    print "YES!!! \n";}
else   {     print "NOOOO!!! \n";  }
```

Answer (score 4):

maybe try with "\Q" to escape special char

```
my $test1 = 'my?test';
my $test2 = 'this is a my?test blah test';

if ($test2 =~ /\Q$test1/)    {    print "YES!!! \n";}
else   {     print "NOOOO!!! \n";  }
```

ouput `YES!!!`

Answer (score 3):

[quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) can handle special regex characters.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $test1 = quotemeta 'my?test';
my $test2 = 'this is a my?test blah test';

if ($test2 =~ /$test1/)    {    print "YES!!! \n";}
else   {     print "NOOOO!!! \n";  }

{
    my $test1 = quotemeta 'mytest';
    my $test2 = 'this is a mytest blah test';

    if ($test2 =~ /$test1/)    {    print "YES!!! \n";}
    else   {     print "NOOOO!!! \n";  }
}
```

Prints:

`YES!!!
YES!!!`

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked in CPAN for an existing module that might help you?  From [PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=733540), I found references to Apache::ParseLog and Apache::LogRegEx