# perl one line regex escape ^ character

Tags: regex, perl

I have line starting with ^ character, I want to start of line and ^charater. but its not wokring.

```
echo "^./mnt/" |perl -slane ' print if m#^$line$#o' -- -line="^./mnt/"
```

how can I match this regex with input regularexpression passed as argument.

this one works, but I would like to make it work with-in perl.

```
#echo "^./mnt/" |perl -slane ' print if m#^$line$#o' -- -line="\\^./mnt/"
^./mnt/
```

Thanks
SR

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I handle special characters in a Perl regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576435/how-do-i-handle-special-characters-in-a-perl-regex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert text into a regex pattern, use quotemeta (perhaps via \Q..\E).

```
echo "^./mnt/" |perl -slne'print if /^\Q$line\E$/' -- -line="^./mnt/"
```

In this case, you could just use

```
echo "^./mnt/" |perl -slne'print if $_ eq $line' -- -line="^./mnt/"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the special characters in your argument (just as if it was embedded directly in the regex).

`echo "^./mnt/" |perl -slane ' print if m#^$line$#o' -- -line="\^\.\/mnt\/"`

Comment: my problem is I Pass ^./mnt/ as argument to perl, how will I esacpe inside the perl?

Answer (score 1):

maybe  `m#^\Q$line\E#`  or `m#^\Q$_\E#` but not sure because I'm on windoz box

Comment: yes, it worked `echo "^./mnt/" |perl -slane ' print if m#^\Q$line\E$#' -- -line="^./mnt/"
^./mnt/`