# Perl regexp matching for strings with special characters

Tags: regex, perl

I have list of substrings which I need to match within a list of URL strings. The substrings have special characters like '|', '*', '-', '+' etc. If the URL strings contains that substring I need to do some operation. But for now lets just say I will print "TRUE" in the console.

I did this by first reading from the list of substrings and putting it into a hash. I then tried to perform a simple Regexp match of the entire list for each URL until a match is found. The code is something like this.

```
open my $ADS, '<', $ad_file or die "can't open $ad_file";

while(<$ADS>) {
        chomp;

        $ads_list_hash{$lines} = $_;
        $lines ++;
 }  

close $ADS;

open my $IN, '<', $inputfile or die "can't open $inputfile";      
my $first_line = <$IN>;

while(<$IN>) {      
       chomp;       

       my @hhfile = split /,/;       
       for my $count (0 .. $lines) {

            if($hhfile[9] =~ /$ads_list_hash{$count}/) {
                print "$hhfile[9]\t$ads_list_hash{$count}\n";

                print "TRUE !\n";
                last;
            }
       }

 }

 close $IN;
```

The problem is that the substrings have a lot of special characters which is causing errors in the match `$hhfile[9] =~ /$ads_list_hash{$count}/`. Few examples are;

```
+adverts/
.to/ad.php|
/addyn|*|adtech;
```

I get an error in lines like these which basically says "Quantifier follows nothing in regexp". Do I need to chanhge something in the regexp matching syntax to avoid these?

Comment: If you're just trying to find a substring, then a regex seems a bit overkill... Is there a reason why [index](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/index.html) doesn't do what you need?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I handle special characters in a Perl regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576435/how-do-i-handle-special-characters-in-a-perl-regex)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to escape the special characters in the string.

Enclosing the string between `\Q` and `\E` will do the job:

```
if($hhfile[9] =~ /\Q$ads_list_hash{$count}\E/) {
```