# Why is split on `|` (pipe) not working as expected?

Tags: perl, variables, split, separator

I have a string that I want to split. But the separator is determined at runtime and so I need to pass it as a variable.

Something like `my @fields = split(/$delimiter/,$string);` doesn't work. Any thoughts?

---

Input:

```
abcd|efgh|23
```

Expected Output:

```
abcd
efgh
23
```

Comment: Your input, real output, and expected output would be immensely useful information...

Comment: You do not have a "delimiter", you have a "separator". A "delimiter" marks the limits, ie. it is at both ends, like double quotes. A "separator" goes in between elements, like the "|" in your example input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I handle special characters in a Perl regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576435/how-do-i-handle-special-characters-in-a-perl-regex)

Comment: thanks this helped me solve a problem i was working on

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to escape your delimiter, since it's a special character in regular expressions.

Option 1:

```
$delimiter = quotemeta($delimiter);
my @fields = split /$delimiter/, $string;
```

Option 2:

```
my @fields = split /\Q$delimiter/, $string;
```

Comment: For more information, see: `perldoc perlretut`, `perldoc perlre` and search for /\\Q/ and see `perldoc -f quotemeta`.

Comment: The argument to `split` is not a delimiter, but a separator.

Comment: Not according to `perldoc -f split`: "Anything matching PATTERN is taken to be a delimiter separating the fields."