# How to check for | in doing substitution in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, expression

I have a string with the following data in it

```
"email@domain.com | firstname | lastname"
```

I want to replace `| lastname` with a different value. If I use `s/` to do a substitution, what do i need to do to the | to get it to recognize. If I do

```
$foo =~ s/ lastname/fillertext/;
```

it works fine. but if I do

```
$foo =~ s/ | lastname/fillertext/;
```

it doesn't work. I tried to do - `\|/ lastname`, `"| lastname"`, `'| lastname'`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I handle special characters in a Perl regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576435/how-do-i-handle-special-characters-in-a-perl-regex)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`|` has a special meaning in a regular expression; if you want to match a literal `|`, you just need to escape it:

```
$foo =~ s/ \| lastname/fillertext/;
```