# Using variables that contain special characters in Perl regexes

Tags: regex, perl, variables, special-characters

I'm trying to search an array for lines that contain $inbucket[0].  Some of my $inbucket[0] values include special characters.  This script does exactly what I want it to, until I hit a special character.

I want the query to be case insensitive, match any part of the string $var, and process the special characters literally, as if they weren't special.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
sub loopthru() {
    warn "Loopthru begun on $inbucket[0]\n";
    foreach $c (@chat) {
        $var = $c->msg;
        $lookfor2 = $inbucket[0];
        if ( $var =~ /$lookfor2/i ) {
            ($to,$from) = split('-',$var);
            $from =~ s/\.$//;
            print MYFILE "$to\t$from\n";
            &fillbucket($to);
            &fillbucket($from);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I handle special characters in a Perl regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576435/how-do-i-handle-special-characters-in-a-perl-regex)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html), which returns the value of its argument with all non-"word" characters backslashed.

```
$lookfor2 = quotemeta $inbucket[0];
```

Or you can use the `\Q` escape, which is discussed in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html). In short, it will quote (disable) pattern metacharacters until `\E` is encountered.

```
if ( $var =~ /\Q$lookfor2/i ) {
```

Comment: A trip to the obvious:  \Q ..... \E doesn't escape sigils ($ or @); Variable interpolation occurs at an earlier stage in the parsing.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for 
`$var =~ /\Q$lookfor2/i`

[perl faq](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#How-can-I-quote-a-variable-to-use-in-a-regex)