# How to match '(' using a regex?

Tags: regex, perl

When I do this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $s = 'dfgdfg5 )';
my $a = '5 )';
my $b = '567';

$s =~ s/$a/$b/g;
print Dumper $s;
```

I get

```
Unmatched ) in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/5 ) <-- HERE / at ./test.pl line 11.
```

The problem is that `$a` have a `(`.

How do I prevent the regex from failing?

**Update**

The string in `$a` do I get from a database query, so I can't change it. Or would it be possible to make an `$a2` where "something" searches for `)` and replaces them with `\)`?

Comment: I have updated the post. The problem is I can't edit `$a`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576435/how-do-i-handle-special-characters-in-a-perl-regex

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to escape it. Either manually by adding backslash in front of it, or by using [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) or the [`\Q` sequence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Escape-sequences) inside the regex:

```
$a = quotemeta($a);
```

Or

```
$s =~ /\Q$a/$b/g;
```

**ETA:** This is a good option if you want to match literal strings from a database query.

You should also be aware that it is not a good idea to use `$a` and `$b` as variables, since they will mask the predefined variables that are used with [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html). E.g. `sort { $a <=> $b } @foo`.

Comment: That's more appropriate to this problem than my solution.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is to backslash escape the paren.  `my $a = '5 \)';`  In your case, as your post mentions, you aren't the one creating the strings, so literally escaping them isn't an option.

It may be simpler to just wrap the variable that's being interpolated by the regex inside of a \Q ... \E.

`$s =~ s/\Q$a\E/$b/g;`

The `quotemeta()` function may also be helpful to you, depending on how your code is factored.  With that option you would pass $a through quotemeta before interpolating it in the regex.  \Q...\E is probably easier in this situation, but if your code is simplified by using quotemeta instead, it's there for you.

Answer (score 3):

Use `\)` instead of just `)`. `)` is special because it's normally used for capturing patterns so you need to escape it first.

Answer (score 2):

Escape the parentheses with a backslash:

```
my $a = '5 \)'oi;
```

Or use \Q inside the regexp:

```
$s =~ s/\Q$a/$b/g;
```

Also when storing regexps in a variable, you should look into the regexp quote operator: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators

```
my $a = qr/5 \)/oi;
```

Answer (score 1):

In Perl regular expression you need to mask special chars with a backslash `\`.

Try

```
my $a = '5 \)';
my $b = '567';

$s =~ s/$a/$b/g;
```

For details and a good start see [`perldoc perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html)

**Update:** I didn't know the RE came from a database. Well, the code above works nevertheless. The hint for the tutorial still applies.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to escape the brackets, ie replace `)` with `\)`